# Using variable from different $_POST

Tags: php, session, mysqli, session-variables

Let's say my code looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST["reset"])){
   //selects email and phoneNo from database based on values entered in form
   $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
}else if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    //line 68 -- $rePas = "UPDATE user SET 'password' = '" .password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT) . "' WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'";
}
```

I have `session_start();` at the beginning of the page, outside any if's etc.
I enter the page to see a form that asks me to input email and phone number, then I click `Reset` button, if the sql code returns something the form is changed to another form that asks me to input password. Once I do that I press `Submit`button and I get `$_POST['submit']` I get `Notice: Undefined index: email in ... on line 68`

I can't understand why the session variable is set to null after pressing submit button, is there anyway to pass a variable through two forms, if that makes sense?
I have looked through stackoverflow similar question yet I couldnt find a working solution.

Looks like this piece of code and explanation is not enough therefore here is the link to full file code: https://pastebin.com/fDEBCakp

Comment: check that you actually receive $_POST['email'], the field may not be submitted or its name could be spelled different.

Comment: is `$_SESSION['email']` set before the if statement / anywhere else? because if not.. then why would you expect it to hold a value in the else if statement?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs
`$_SESSION['email']` i set in the first if statement. Then I am trying to use it in the second one.

Comment: @Juan
I did, everything is fine

Comment: Except your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: @hDDen there's your problem, either define it outside the conditional statement or define it in both condition statements

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs alright so I added `$_SESSION['email'] = ' ';` at the top of the page. Yet the value from the first if does not stay inside the session. I can't assign `$_POST` to `$_SESSION['email']` at the top of the page since `$_POST` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Dump the `$_POST` and `$_SESSION` data to the screen and show us what you see.  When in doubt, print it out.

Comment: @hDDen did you do that before or after `session_start()`?

Comment: @mickmackusa I always use print to debug $_POST shows the value assigned to it and so does session in the FIRST if statement. Then in the second one its empty..

Comment: I added full code in pastebin, maybe this will be easier now.

Comment: Your `for` is not using `=` and that value is bound the `id` attribute of your target element.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: I think it only makes sense to commit unsafe user-input (`$_POST['email']`) to `$_SESSION['email']` ONLY after it has been confirmed to exist in the database.  Currently, you are blindly accepting the submitted data -- not good.

Comment: Why are you INNER JOINing anyhow? Please show us some sample data (check points) as you run through your seemingly convoluted process so that we can isolate the earliest point of failure.  And, or course, show us that you will be using prepared statements with placeholders and parameter binding -- like a good programmer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    $emailid = $_POST['email'];
    echo "email - ". $emailid;
}
?>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"> 
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to explain your code, rather than just dump it. This serves as a fairly poor answer.

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense to me since in my submit form I have only password input. Email is in the first form.

Comment: actually it just post for one field alone, so it works fine. so you can add fields as you need